Conditional Lead(), to retrieve the next row only when a condition is met?
I am looking to retrieve the first "Sales_Date" for each "Account_ID", however in my dataset there are entries where the first sales are actually not sales as the product transacted is a sample and thus $0 revenue. For those entries, I would like to skip it and take the next Sales Date as the first "Sales_Date". I have attempted the below query but run into the issue where some transactions may contain both a sample and an actual product in the same transaction. This results in duplicate rows with the same Account_ID being retrieved in the output. I am not sure how to change the query to resolve this and produce the desired outcome table below.
UNIQUE_ID AS(
SELECT
   DISTINCT 
    ACCOUNT_ID,
    MIN(SALES_DATE) FIRST_SALES_DATE
FROM
    Sample_Data_Table
GROUP BY
    ACCOUNT_ID
)
SELECT
   ACCOUNT_ID,
   (
     CASE
       WHEN PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION LIKE ('%Sample%') THEN 
       LEAD (SALES_DATE,1,NULL) OVER PARTITION BY (ACCOUNT_ID) ORDER BY ACCOUNT_ID ASC))
     END
   ) NEW_FIRST_SALES_DATE
FROM
   UNIQUE_ID

Sample_Data_Table as follows:



ACCOUNT_ID
ACCOUNT_NAME
PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION
REVENUE
SALES_DATE




1
A
Sample  A
0
2005-01-05


1
A
Product B
253
2005-01-05


3
C
Product C
1654
2005-02-05


4
D
Product D
316
2005-03-08


5
E
Product E
123
2005-04-08


6
F
Product F
587
2005-05-09


7
G
Product G
987
2005-06-09


8
H
Product H
58
2005-07-10


9
I
Product I
65
2005-08-10


10
J
Product J
2189
2005-09-10


1
A
Product P
6
2006-03-15



Desired Outcome as follows:



ACCOUNT_ID
NEW_FIRST_SALES_DATE




3
2005-02-05


4
2005-03-08


5
2005-04-08


6
2005-05-09


7
2005-06-09


8
2005-07-10


9
2005-08-10


10
2005-09-10


1
2006-03-15




your logic does not follow your examples, please show more multi rows, with and without zero renues and have less rows with the same sate (3-10 add no new value)

SELECT
    ACCOUNT_ID,
    MIN(SALES_DATE) AS FIRST_SALES_DATE
FROM Sample_Data_Table
WHERE
    NOT (
        PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Sample%'
        OR REVENUE = 0
    )
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_ID


You question does a poor job of providing example data that demostraints your desire, which is also poorly worded.
with data(ACCOUNT_ID, ACCOUNT_NAME, PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, REVENUE, SALES_DATE) as (
    select * from values
    (1,  'A', 'Sample A', 0, '2005-01-05'::date),
    (1,  'A', 'Product B', 253, '2005-01-05'::date),
    (1,  'A', 'Product P', 6,   '2006-03-15'::date),
    
    (2,  'A', 'Product B', 253, '2005-01-05'::date),
    (2,  'A', 'Product P', 6,   '2006-03-15'::date),
     
    (3,  'A', 'Product B', 253, '2005-01-05'::date),
    (3,  'A', 'Product P', 6,   '2006-03-15'::date),
    (3,  'C', 'Product C', 1654, '2005-02-05'::date),
    
    (4,  'A', 'Sample A', 0, '2005-01-05'::date),
    (4,  'A', 'Product B', 253, '2005-01-05'::date),

    (5,  'E', 'Product E', 123, '2005-04-08'::date)
    
    (6,  'E', 'Product E', 0,   '2005-04-08'::date)
    
)

you describe some rules like, ignore rows with zero revenue, so that could be filtered out, and your resutls show when there is 1 or more future rows take those, otherwise take this.
but you also only show one row with 2 sales, and you only have one output row, so the above "logic" does not actually hold. So you are appear to be asking for the second row of any set, unless there is only 1 in the set, and then take that.
can you show what results you expect with the above data.
